# line numbering with listings and excluding range markers

Tags: numbering, listings, line-numbering, line

Hello everybody,

my question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178301/linenumbering-with-listings-package-in-latex but I am trying to do the same with line range markers. The problem is the following: The line numbers become 2,6,11,16 etc. when using `includerangemarker=false`

Here a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    rangebeginprefix=//\ begin:\ ,
    rangeendprefix=//\ end:\ ,
    includerangemarker=false, % this causes the problem
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=5,    
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true
}


\begin{document}                                                        
    \lstinputlisting[linerange=main-main]{./HelloWorld.java}
\end{document}
```

and  HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    // begin: main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");      
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    // end: main
}
```

How can I exclude the range markers and still get the lines 1,5,10,15 etc. numbered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work but no guaranties that it doesn't break something else…

`\lst@DefRangeB@` is one of a very few places in `listings.sty` where `\lst@ifincluderangemarker ... \else ... \fi` is used. The code below adds `\global\advance\c@lstnumber\m@ne` to the *false* branch, i.e. it reduces the line number by one if `includerangemarker` is false.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lst@DefRangeB@
  {\lst@InitLstNumber\fi}% search
  {\lst@InitLstNumber\global\advance\c@lstnumber\m@ne\fi}% replace
  {}% success
  {\err}% failure
\makeatother

\lstset{
  rangebeginprefix = //\ begin:\ ,
  rangeendprefix   = //\ end:\ ,
  includerangemarker = false , % this causes the problem
  numbers     = left ,
  stepnumber  = 5 , 
  firstnumber = 1 ,
  numberfirstline = true
}

% just to keep the example in one file:
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{HelloWorld.java}
public class HelloWorld {
    // begin: main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");      
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    // end: main
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}                                                        

\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily,linerange=main-main]{HelloWorld.java}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested it in a document with multiple `\lstinline`-commands and some normal listing-environments and it seems to break nothing. Could you please explain your patch a bit to avoid mistakes when using it?